# Match regex with fixed length and add trailing whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble creating a regex (Java) to match the following pattern:

1. Starts with **1** or **2** digits
2. Followed by letters **M** or **MS**
3. **Must** be 7 characters long. Padding at the end must be done with whitespaces.

Valid inputs:

- 2M, 2MS, 10M, 10MS (and their respective trailing whitespaces)

What I have so far:

`[\\d{1,2}MS?\\s]{7}`

It enforces the length and allows for whitespaces, but that's about it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
^(?=.{7}$)\\d{1,2}MS?\\s*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line, not mandatory when using matches()
(?=.{7}$)   : lookahead, make sure we have exactly 7 characters
\\d{1,2}    : 1 or 2 digits
M           : M
S?          : optional S
\\s*        : 0 or more spaces
$           : end of line, not mandatory when using matches()
```

Comment: You missed the `M`, and there is no need for `^` and `$` when using `matches()`, except inside the lookahead.

Comment: For a complete answer, you should explain the regex parts.

Comment: Alright. This works. Only had to make a slight modification to the lookahead because this was only a part of my string, but it worked nonetheless. Thanks!